# Does anyone know where I could get free GPS data on certain types of locations for any country

Tags: database, web, gps, location

I am currently building a web application server which essential would allow a client application to send it's current location and query on the server for the closet locations of a certain location type, examples of location types would be nearest payphone, nearest restaurant or nearest gas station.

Does anyone know where I could get the GPS data for free? I would eventually like to have data for pretty much any country in the world.

It would be preferred that the GPS location data to be in decimal format, I am flexible with the file format containing the data.

Answer (score 2):

[OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) may contain the location types you're looking for, and if they don't you could always convince the community to start mapping  them.

[LinkedGeoData](http://linkedgeodata.org) also contains geospatial information (based on OpenStreetMap, but with the potential for linking to other datasets), and may provide a way to extract the information you're looking for, although this is something I've only recently come across, so can't say one way or another; I mention it in case it proves useful to you.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

check out this site. it provides access to data for GPS markers, etc as a service or if you prefer, you can download its entire database. hope this helps!

http://www.geonames.org/

Comment: Thanks for the link, however, the website does not return any of the location types I'm after.